# dependencies for com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to import below mentioned libraries in Android Studio. But api is undetectable by the Studio. What could be the problem?

```
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
```

In gradle, I am using these dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after adding the dependencies as follows:-

```
 compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v2-rev87-1.19.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your imports are from [google-http-java-client](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client) and the [Drive Java API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2), neither of which have anything to do with the [Google Drive Android API](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/drive.html).

Per the [setup instructions for google-http-java-client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/setup#android), they **do not** recommend using the Java API for Android development - instead, you should use the Google Play Services equivalents (which exist in most cases).